# Caching docker image in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, caching, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to split building and pushing of the docker image into two gitlab ci jobs. Both jobs are running on my local gitlab runner. For the `push` job, I want to cache the docker image previously built within `build` job:

```
stages:
  - build
  - push

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
  cache:
  - Not sure how to cache the image

push:
  stage: push
  script:
  - docker push cached image
```

I tried to read about that but was unable to find the satisfied solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, gitlab cache is not meant to be used to cache docker images. There's [gitlab registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/) for that - check it out.

However, if the jobs are run on the same machine, you don't necessarily need registry. You can just use the image you have locally. You can simply copy contents of the first image with the help of Dockerfile. Small example, copying the built code from the "build" image:

```
#building:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
dotnet build . . .

#pushing:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet/runtime:5.0
COPY --from=build /builtCode ./
```